# 4 layouts 1 page in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with which I want 4 instances of a layout displayed on the screen at a time, and you scroll to look at the next 4. This means I either need to add 4 instances of the layout to a single page, or I need to tell the ViewPager to scroll 4 pages at a time. I'd like to do this without making 4 copies of a layout in the same xml. Here's how I'm handling this now:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
{   
    LinearLayout toReturn = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    toReturn.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    for(int i = position; i < position + 4; i++)
    {
        View layout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.viewpager_fragment_layout, container, false);

        toReturn.addView(layout);
    }

    container.addView(toReturn);

    return toReturn;
}
```

The result is the same as though I were adding each layout to the ViewPager 1 at a time instead of grouping them up into a single layout. It displays 4 layouts on the screen at a time, but when you scroll, you only move past 1 layout at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `getPageWidth()` in your `PagerAdapter` to return the portion of the screen to use for a page. For four pages at a time, returning `0.25` should work.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/MultiView1) demonstrating this. Also [here is a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html) outlining this technique and a couple of others.

---

With regards to your current code, I do not know for certain how you are determining that 
"when you scroll, you only move past 1 layout at a time". After all, since you are not changing anything in the layouts, they all look the same.

Hence, I am going to make two assumptions, that would seem to fit your described symptoms:

1. There is code that you elected not to show between your `inflate()` call and your `addView()` call.
2. The code in question is populating the widgets based on `position`.

Bear in mind that `position` is the *page index*, not the *layout index*.

Let's suppose that you have 12 total layouts. You want to show those in 3 pages in a `ViewPager`. Hence, `getPageCount()` should be returning 3. And instead of:

```
 for(int i = position; i < position + 4; i++) {
```

I would expect to see:

```
 for(int layout_offset = 0; layout_offset < 4; layout_offset++) {
    int i=(position*4)+layout_offset;
```

(though I would have named `i` to be `layout_index` or something)

Comment: I already am. I guess I didn't specify. There already are 4 layouts on the screen at a time, but when you scroll, you only scroll through 1 layout at a time, instead of the desired 4.

Comment: @KairisCharm: How many pages are changed depends upon how much and how quickly you swipe. If you take my sample project and change it to return `0.25f`, you will see that if you swipe from the far right to the far left, you will move three or four pages, depending a bit on the speed of the swipe.

Comment: But I never want it to scroll only 1 at a time. I want to force it to move 4 at a time. Is there no way to do this?

Comment: @KairisCharm: Not via the `getPageWidth()` technique. I posted a link to a blog post that covers a couple of other options that you could consider. Then again, I have no idea why you think that you have "four pages at a time", when there does not appear to be anything in your UI that wishes to for them to actually be "four pages" instead of one page with slightly-more-complex contents.

Comment: Not 4 pages at a time. 4 layouts at a time. The desired behavior is what you described: "one page with slightly-more-complex contents." I thought that's what my above code would provide. But instead, It's treating each of those 4 layouts as a full page (but taking up 1/4 of the screen) instead of 1/4 of a page.

Comment: @KairisCharm: Then just have each page be made up of four layouts, wrapped in a horizontal `LinearLayout`.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do in the code that I posted above. See, I loop through each of those 4 layouts adding them to a single LinearLayout which then gets returned. But still each one of those 4 layouts is behaving like a full page. (Maybe my code is deceptive because I named a variable "page" when I meant "layout").

Comment: You were correct that there is some code I left out. I am passing the TextViews etc to another object to populate each layout with unique data. You were also correct that my looping logic was off. But now that it's fixed, I'm finding that the ViewPager is only accepting the 1st layout in "toReturn". The other 3 were never being added to begin with.

Comment: @KairisCharm: Try the two-parameter `addView()` method and pass in a suitable `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. Or, use Hierarchy View (or **`uiautomatorviewer`**) to see what's going on.

Comment: I think I see where you're going. You think the 1st layout is taking up the whole space of the page, and the other 3 have no room. I think you're right. But using the 2-parm addView() is tricky, because the parent fragment hasn't been laid out by that point in the code, so I don't know which dimensions to send it. I'll look at it more and let you know what I find tomorrow.

Comment: @KairisCharm: "But using the 2-parm addView() is tricky, because the parent fragment hasn't been laid out by that point in the code, so I don't know which dimensions to send it." -- width of 0 and weight of 1, if you want them all equally-sized.

Comment: But what about the height?

Comment: @KairisCharm: match_parent, presumably.

Comment: Forget I said that - Realized that 30 seconds after I said it.

Comment: That's it. You nailed it. I went ahead and marked your answer as correct just to give you credit  for helping me. Thank you! ^_^